# Proof big omega of 1^k+2^k+..+n^k

Tags: math, big-o, inequality

Question:

```
1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k is big omega of n^(k+1)
1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k => cn^(k+1)
```

Hi, I need some help to figure out how I can prove this. I am trying to avoid induction and proving it as simple as possible.

Comment: Hey man.. I think you'd need to define big omega. Try proof by induction. But I don't think this is really a programming question. GL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integrals. Your sum is larger than the

> integral of x^k from 0 to n

and smaller than the

> integral of x^k from 1 to n+1.

Thus you even get a Theta class. And c=1/(k+1).